# ODP.NET - deploy without installation ORACLE CLIENT - big size of oraociei11.dll

Tags: c#, deployment, odp.net, oracleclient

I use ODP.NET in my WPF app for access to Oracle 10g db. I dont want instal oracle client on users computers so I copied these dll to realese folder:

- oci.dll
- ocijdbc11.dll
- ociw32.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- orannzsbb11.dll
- orasql11.dll
- OraOps11w.dll
- oraocci11.dll - 706 KB
- oraociei11.dll - 126,55 KB

I think that last two dlls **oraocci11.dll and oraociei11.dll**  has same functionality but
oraociei11.dll is realy big.

I would like remove oraociei11.dll from my project. I did it but application crash if I dont have oraociei11.dll in realease folder.

Maybe I am wrong and they dont have same functionality

It is possible remove this dll.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the .net dlls are just a kind of wrapper around the native dll you mention that **needs** to be distributed. So there is no other way than to distribute your application with all the megabytes of native dlls.

For what is more there are also **license restrictions** as to the distribution of those dlls. I am pretty sure that the Oracle client libraries are not free to redistribute in any other way than deploying the whole installer pack (which is sadly pretty large and quite complicated to configure) and run it on the client.

Comment: I don't agree with the licensing part. Oracle itself provides an [Instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) that doesn't need installation. The license grants rights to redistribute: "Please note that Instant Client is provided under a separate OTN Development and Distribution License for Instant Client that allows most licensees to download, redistribute, and deploy in production environments, without charge"